# Using NSMutableArray in a class

Tags: objective-c, arrays, class, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Whenever I try to add something to my array in the method nothing gets added to the array. I'm wanting it to when you press the button it will add a new object to the array.

```
//  JBNumberGeneration.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface JBNumberGeneration : NSObject {
 IBOutlet NSTextField *displayLabel;
 int randNum;
 int level;
 int i;
 NSMutableArray* userNumSequence;
}

-(IBAction)logSequenceNumber:(id)sender;

@end


//  JBNumberGeneration.m

#import "JBNumberGeneration.h"


@implementation JBNumberGeneration

-(IBAction)logSequenceNumber:(id)sender{
  NSString *titleOfButton = [sender title];
 int sequenceNumber = [titleOfButton integerValue];

 int count = [userNumSequence count];
 i++;

 [userNumSequence addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sequenceNumber]];

 NSLog(@"Array size: %i", count);
    }
    @end
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you initialized the array somewhere using something like
userNumSequence = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
I could not see that in your code as that would cause nothing to get added.

Comment: Ok I added it in but it seems to create the array and then delete after the function is finished.

Comment: Added it in after "int sequenceNumber = [titleOfButton integerValue];
"

Comment: initialize the array in init for the class JBNumberGeneration

Comment: - (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
                userNumSequence = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
        }
    return self;
}

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm quite new to objective-C.